# Xamarin.Forms: How to add custom HTTP headers in WebView (all requests + css + js)?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, http-headers, xamarin.forms

I already did this with custom WebViewRender and MyWebViewClient, but I think that it can be done better for iOS and Android.
I will appreciate any help. If this can be made easier with only the help of the PCL (Xamarin.Forms)
Thanks!

```
public class WebViewRender : WebViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
        {
            var webView = Control as Android.Webkit.WebView;
            Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                ["Name"] = "value"
            };
            webView.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
            webView.LoadUrl(Control.Url, headers);
        }
    }
}
public class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{
    public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            ["Name"] = "value"
        };
        view.LoadUrl(url, headers);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: No ideas? I will appreciate any help.

Comment: I saw you already tried to override `ShouldOverrideUrlLoading`, you can add headers there, and it is pure in PCL. So, not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Is it possible to add common logic which will work both on Android and iOs?

Comment: yes, it is possible.